# Image URL in App or in Database

Tags: android, mysql

I am making an android app which is going to need a lot of pictures. But I can't have them all in the app since it would be like 10 gigabytes or something. I have read some other questions where they say its smarter to store the url to the pictures in a database. My question is, should the image url be stored in the application itself or in the database?

Comment: I think you should store image urls in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB is a part of the application itself. Is it not? If you are talking about hard-coding , keeping them in DB is better keeping extensibility in mind but would involve extra call to DB.

Hard-coding them would be better performing (How much, you need to test that).

Alternatively you can make use of build tools by storing the urls in a configuration and replacing  them at the time of build. While this solves above two problems, It adds complexity to the code.

So everything has its gives and takes, you need to decide what to chose on your requirements and priorities.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the URLs in a database, you are able to manage your images easier, as you don't have to hardcode everything.

Answer (score 0):

store URL in a DB will more preferable. And you can load the images using [picasso](http:////http://javatechig.com/android/opensource/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android) library would better easier and comfortable way.

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to store image url's in a database, whether that database resides on your phone, or on the server and you fetch it from there using rest services is upto you.
You can use multiple libraries for image lazy loading in your app.

[1]: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader "Universal Image Loader" is by far a very good third party library.
You can also add your own lazy loading algorithms by creating a basic Thread Pool.